# How to customize angular-material grid system?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

It's possible customize the angular-material grid system like bootstrap, by setting columns, gutter-width, etc?
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

The angular-material.scss has some mixins like "flex-properties-for-name", but always will create 20 columns with increments of 5%.

I could override some mixins, but I was looking for other ways to do this.

**Update:**

My first solution was reuse some mixins from the angular-material.scss to create a custom grid.
https://gist.github.com/dilvane/a5418f3f3c5d68cf1059

Does anyone have a different approach?

**Update:**

Issue reported: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6537

Comment: Doesn't <div flex="20">, <div flex="30">, etc. work?

Comment: @camden_kid, <div flex="[0-100]">, every 5... works, but will create 20 columns